# How to refer 2 columns from a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables they are 
1. User { id, name, mobile}
2. Temp_User { id, name, mobile}
3. In_Out { id, intime, outtime}

Now I want to make `id` in `In_Out` as a foreign key and it should refer `User.id` as well as `Temp_User.id`. That is, the `id` value must be present either in `User` or in `Temp_User`.

Is it possible in mysql?
If anyone knows, please give me the `ALTER` command for the `In_Out` table strcture. I have already created the table.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is a faq. Google for variations on your title.

Comment: Yesterday, the last FK post I saw, was this duplicate. The day before, the previous FK post I saw, also was. Part of my comment was "The general case of "common fields used by several tables" is subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism in databases/SQL and is also asked about in questions about multiple/many/two FKs/references/relationships/links to multiple/many/two tables. (But FKs are not usually what the constraints are in that design variant, which is likely related to what you're pointing out.) Essentially, the supertype is things having those fields."

Comment: @philipxy I searched google but with inurl:stackoverflow but I found different Questions like, `refer same element from multiple tables` likewise, which is exactly opposite of my question. But this solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding a flag to the User table that indicates if the user is a temporary user or not:

```
alter table user add is_temp tinyint unsigned default 0 not null;
```

This will allow a simple foreign key reference from In_Out:

```
alter table In_Out 
    change id User_id <Match Data Type And Nullness Here>,
    add constraint User_id_fk foreign key (User_id) references User(id);
```